# Using 2 models in one view in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and I am kindly asking you to help me with this problem:
I have 2 models - Delegation:

```
public int idDelegation { get; set; }
public string Delegation_Name { get; set; }
public string Employee_Name { get; set; }
```

and Project:

```
public int idProject { get; set; }
public string Project_System_Name { get; set; }
public string Project_System_ID { get; set; }
```

I want to display in a view a list of current delegations and projects, with the Edit/Details/Delete options for each one.
I created a ViewModel DelegationProject:

```
public class DelegationProject
{
    public IEnumerable<Delegation> delegations { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Project> projects { get; set; }
}
```

In my Index view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<....ViewModel.DelegationProject>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.delegations.Employee_Name</th>
         <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.delegations.Delegation_Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.delegations.Employee_Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.delegations.Delegation_Name</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { x => x.idDelegation }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { x => x.idDelegation }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { x => x.idDelegation })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

When I run the application, I get these error messages:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Employee_Name' and no extension method 'Employee_Name' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried different things (like List<> or Tuple) from stackoverflow topics and other sites posts, but I wasn't able to use to models in the same view and iterate through them.

Comment: You have not shown your controller code, but you need to be passing a single instance of `DelegationProject` to the view (not a collection of `DelegationProject`) The view needs `@model DelegationProject`.  Then you loops need to be `@foreach (var item in Model.delegations)` and  `@foreach (var item in Model.projects)` (and please go to the help files and lear how to format your question and the code in it)

Comment: Edit your question with the code you tried (and you did not follow the code in my previous comment!)

Comment: Which bit about _edit your question did you not understand_

Comment: I am sorry. Is seems that I cannot format my text according to help. I tried many times. It seems that I will not be able to solve my problem as I cannot format my answer.

Comment: Click the edit link and and your code and ensure its indented 4 spaces (its all in the hep file I linked to). And read my first comment - its `@foreach (var item in Model.delegations)`!

Comment: I used in View:      @model DelegationTracker2.ViewModel.DelegationProject  And I used      foreach (var item in Model.delegations)  but I get this error:      Compiler Error Message: CS1579: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'DelegationTracker2.Models.Delegation' because 'DelegationTracker2.Models.Delegation' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: I give up. Your view model `DelegationProject` contains a property `public IEnumerable<Delegation> delegations { get; set; }` so `foreach (var item in Model.delegations)` will work because property `delegations` is `IEnumerable`. God only knows what other errors you have in your code but you wont edit your question to show it, so best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution for this problem.

The ViewModel DelegationProject remained the same, in my controller for Index action I have:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
DelegationProject viewModel = new DelegationProject();
viewModel.delegations = GetDelegations();
viewModel.projects = GetProjects();
return View(viewModel);
}
```

And I created two methods in the respective controller - GetDelegations() and GetProjects():

```
public List<Delegation> GetDelegations()
{
    var deleg = db.Delegation.Include(d => d.Project);
    var list = new List<Delegation>(deleg).ToList();
    return list;
}

public List<Project> GetProjects()
{

    var projects = db.Project.Include(p => p.Country);
    var list = new List<Project>(projects);
    return list;
}
```

My View looks like this:

```
     @model .......ViewModel.DelegationProject
     @foreach (var item in Model.delegations)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Employee_Name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(itemModel => item.Delegation_Name)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
```

Hope this could be of any help to somebody.